# How to tally up xml attribute values in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I've got the following XML data in a data column in a SQL Server table. I would like to sum up the total value of all the `RecordCount` attribute as I select each table row. How do I go about doing it?

```
<BatchSummary BatchNumber="7" BatchType="SecOwnerTransfer">
    <InterfaceTable TableName="ASR.aps_transferevents" RecordCount="1438" />
    <InterfaceTable TableName="ASR.aps_transferowners" RecordCount="3462" />
    <InterfaceTable TableName="ASR.APS_DeleteTransferEvents" RecordCount="122" />
</BatchSummary>
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<BatchSummary BatchNumber="7" BatchType="SecOwnerTransfer">
      <InterfaceTable TableName="ASR.aps_transferevents" RecordCount="1438" />
      <InterfaceTable TableName="ASR.aps_transferowners" RecordCount="3462" />
      <InterfaceTable TableName="ASR.APS_DeleteTransferEvents" RecordCount="122" />
    </BatchSummary>'),
(N'<BatchSummary BatchNumber="7" BatchType="SecOwnerTransfer">
      <InterfaceTable TableName="ASR.aps_transferevents" RecordCount="1" />
      <InterfaceTable TableName="ASR.aps_transferowners" RecordCount="3" />
      <InterfaceTable TableName="ASR.APS_DeleteTransferEvents" RecordCount="10" />
    </BatchSummary>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , c.value('sum(InterfaceTable/@RecordCount)', 'DECIMAL(12,2)') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/BatchSummary') AS t1(c);

-- to check data type of the RecordCount attribute
SELECT ID
    , TRY_CAST(c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)')  AS INT) AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/BatchSummary/InterfaceTable/@RecordCount') AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------+
| ID | Result |
+----+--------+
|  1 |   5022 |
|  2 |     14 |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: @AndroidCoder, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: It's so awesome! Thank you, Yitzhak! However, when I tried it on my own table, I got "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '0.0E0' to data type int.". What gives? Could it be something wrong with my xml data?

Comment: You need to check your data in the **RecordCount** attribute.

Comment: I added a 2nd SELECT statement to show how to check a data type. It will produce `NULL` value when it is NOT an INT data type. Maybe you have a `DECIMAL` data type

Comment: Figured out. The error is a result of inconsistent xml data, where RecordCount="CStr(ReCnt)" - a programming bug. Your solution is perfect Yitzhak! Much obliged!